# How to mock axios.get() with mockRejectedValue

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

I have a function which does

```
      axios
      .get(//URL)
      .then((response) => {
        return res.json({ /*build response*/ });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         return res.status(500).json({ status: error.response.status, error: error.response.data });
      }
```

I am trying to mock the error object in the test

```
  it("returns 500", async () => {
    axios.get.mockRejectedValue(new Error({ response: { 
    status: 500, data: "Internal Server Error" }}));
    const resp = await request(app).get("/");
    //expect ....

});
```

This is not working for me, I get `thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test`.. What I am missing here?

It works when I mock a positive response

```
     axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ mockResponse });
```

Comment: Try this `jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockRejectedValue()`

Comment: Tried `jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockRejectedValue(new Error("Test"))` Still the same issue. Thanks though.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)